# Android JNI/C++: how to add properly a lib with .h and .cpp files?

Tags: java, android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am a newbie with JNI in Android Studio.

I created an empty Android Java/C++ project, and now I want to add the .cpp and .h files of a third party library in order to compile them in my project.

Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

Here is the content of MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testcpp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.testcpp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        // Should I add here something like  System.loadLibrary("mythirdpartylib"); ???
    }

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = binding.sampleText;
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

Here is the content of the CMakeLists.txt file at the root of cpp folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

# Declares and names the project.
project("testcpp")

add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp )
find_library(log-lib log )
target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} )

add_subdirectory(mythirdpartylib)
```

Code in my native-lib.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

 #include "mythirdpartylib/a.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL

Java_com_example_testcpp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";

// I would like to be able to call some code from mythirdpartylibrary, for example:
// std::string string2 = mythirdpartylib::getStringFromLib();

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

My problem is that I have the following error when I click on any of the .cpp files in folder /mythordpartylib:

> This file is not part of the project. Please include it in the
> appropriate build file (build.gradle, CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk)
> and sync the project

[image]

I added this in /mythirdpartlib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project("testcpp") # Should I include this line in this subfolder ???
FILE(GLOB MyCSources *.cpp)
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

So, how should I do to include properly mythirdpartylib in my project ? What should I do to include the .cpp files of this lib in my compilation ? Once done, will thirdpartylib be compiled in libnative-lib.so or will I have an additional libmythirdpartylib.so ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the lib is only cpp and h file then

in cmakelists.txt

```
add_library(native-lib SHARED first_your_library.cpp native-lib.cpp)
```

If you want to include all cpp files in this cmakelists main directory with subfolders

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES1 "mythirdpartylib/*.cpp") //here list all (cpp) files in mythirdpartylib folder in the root folder where CMakeLists.txt is situated



add_library(native-lib SHARED PORT_DEF.h PATH_DEF.cpp share/request_callbacks.h ${SOURCES1} native-lib.cpp)
```

If headers use cpp file you include cpp file not the header one ( will cause undefined references) if it is only a header you add it, the compile order (which files you put first is important too)

---

This is my full CMaakeLists.txt file

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES1 "share/*.cpp")



add_library(art3dcadc SHARED PORT_DEF.h PATH_DEF.cpp share/request_callbacks.h ${SOURCES1} gl_code.cpp)
#set(bass-lib "C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SDL2-2.0.9/ART3DCAD/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libbass.so")
#add_library(bass-lib SHARED IMPORTED)

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(art3dcadc
                      android
                      log 
                      EGL
                      GLESv2)
                      #-pthread -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lv4lconvert)
```

I see that you have cmakelists for the lib too, i dunno how to merge one with another, you could just inculde library files into main cmakelists as above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don 't understand what are the following files in your answer: first_your_library.cpp,  request_callbacks.h, PORT_DEF.h and PATH_DEF.cpp. May you give more details? Thanks

Comment: THESE request_callback.h, PORT_DEF.h and PATH_DEF.cpp are my own project files that you remove from cmakelists, they are for the reference [THE KEY WORD WAS ${SOURCES1} which includes all cpp files in specified folder]. You have a.cpp, b.cpp and c.cpp so first open CMakeList.txt in mythirdpartylib folder and see which cpp files are compiled first (i assume a,b,c respectively) then your line should look like add_library(native-lib SHARED mythirdpartylib/a.cpp mythirdpartylib/b.cpp mythirdpartylib/c.cpp native-lib.cpp)

Comment: There is a simplier solution to that if you have properly define cmakelists.txt and defined project(prj_name) in it (as a file in the library) then add_subdirectory("path") then target_link_libraries( something prj_name)